# How can I customize the navigation bar in the headline of Singapore theme in beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes

I use the Singapore theme in my beamer presentation, I want to remove the bullet of the inactive sections as in the next picture.

[image]

Here is minimal code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
 test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find where the Singapore theme defines its headline, open `beamerthemeSingapore.sty` and find what `outer` theme is loaded. You will see the line `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}` and hence it is `beamerouterthememiniframes.sty`. In there we need to find the `headline` template, it is defined below:

`\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme}`

As `Singapore` sets `[subsection=false]`, we don't need the `\ifbeamer` part. We can leave the other parts, what is important is `\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}` which prints the navigation part. However what you want there is `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}` because this prints only sections horizontally. Altogether this results in:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme sections only}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
        \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
 test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And visually it becomes:

[image]